# Removing case sensitivity Node subfolder

Tags: html, linux, node.js, web

I have a Linux webserver using node which hosts a directory containing a static index.html file. I am wondering how I can make it so a user getting to the correct URL does not rely upon case sensitivity.

Currently, server.com/caa/ points to something different than server.com/CAA/ -- the directory holding index.html is lowercase "caa"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some middleware that coverts all urls to lower case? Heres an example of one way of doing this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url.toLowerCase();
  next()
});
```

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: are you using express?